# Shell Script - Make directory if it doesn't exist

Tags: shell, directory, mkdir

I want to enter the name of a directory and check if it exists.
If it doesn't exist I want to create but I get the error `mkdir: cannot create directory'./' File exists`

My code says that the file exists even though it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
echo "Enter directory name"
read dirname

if [[ ! -d "$dirname" ]]
then
    if [ -L $dirname]
then
    echo "File doesn't exist. Creating now"
    mkdir ./$dirname
    echo "File created"
    else
        echo "File exists"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Why `mkdir ./$dirname` and not just `mkdir "$dirname"`?

Comment: When I leave out ./ it says cannot create - no such file or directory

Comment: Try quoting, maybe you have some spaces around and it is trying to do `mkdir ./ your_dir` instead of `mkdir ./your_dir`. So you should use `mkdir "$dirname"` alone.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ```
> if [ -L $dirname]
> ```

Look at the error message produced by this line: “[: missing `]'” or some such (depending on which shell you're using). You need a space inside the brackets. You also need double quotes around the variable expansion unless you use double brackets; you can either [learn the rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748), or use a simple rule: **always use double quotes around variable substitution and command substitution** — `"$foo"`, `"$(foo)"`.

```
if [ -L "$dirname" ]
```

Then there's a logic error: you're creating the directory only if there is a symbolic link which does not point to a directory. You presumably meant to have a negation in there.

Don't forget that the directory might be created while your script is running, so it's possible that your check will show that the directory doesn't exist but the directory will exist when you try to create it. [Never do “check then do”, always do “do and catch failure”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

The right way to create a directory if it doesn't exist is

```
mkdir -p -- "$dirname"
```

(The double quotes in case `$dirname` contains whitespace or globbing characters, the `--` in case it starts with `-`.)

Answer (score 9):

Try this code:

```
echo "Enter directory name"
read dirname

if [ ! -d "$dirname" ]
then
    echo "File doesn't exist. Creating now"
    mkdir ./$dirname
    echo "File created"
else
    echo "File exists"
fi
```

Output Log:

```
Chitta:~/cpp/shell$ ls
dir.sh

Chitta:~/cpp/shell$ sh dir.sh
Enter directory name
New1
File doesn't exist. Creating now
File created

chitta:~/cpp/shell$ ls
New1  dir.sh

Chitta:~/cpp/shell$ sh dir.sh
Enter directory name
New1
File exists

Chitta:~/cpp/shell$ sh dir.sh
Enter directory name
New2
File doesn't exist. Creating now
File created

Chitta:~/cpp/shell$ ls
New1  New2  dir.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

try this: `ls yourdir 2>/dev/null||mkdir yourdir`, which is tiny and concise and fulfils your task.

Comment: Please add some more details why this approach is better.. currently this is probably  a comment.

Comment: The idea here is to check whether you are able to `ls` the directory. The `ls` command will return a non-zero exit code if the directory does not exist and thereby the command on the right-hand side of the `||` clause will be invoked. If the directory exists already, the `ls` command will return `0` - true -  and only the left-hand side of `||` will be evaluated

Answer (score 5):

```
read -p "Enter Directory Name: " dirname
if [[ ! -d "$dirname" ]]
then
        if [[ ! -L $dirname ]]
        then
                echo "Directory doesn't exist. Creating now"
                mkdir $dirname
                echo "Directory created"
        else
                echo "Directory exists"
        fi
fi
```